# Turn a facebook page to an android app

Tags: android, facebook-page

Is it possible to turn a facebook page to android app.To show new posts and send push notification each time a new post is posted ?? Please tell me where to start

Comment: convert a facebook page to android app !

Comment: You can write an app to show that connects to facebook. have a look http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1):

You can try use service page application. https://pageapplication.com

You can create free native android app with only your facebook page wall. if you like push notification you will need to chose some subscription.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
To answer that question. You will first will have to create a server.
Then on your app you will have to send AJAX queries to your server and get response back.

That is the only way you can go about it. So first I would suggest you set up a server. You can use Spring3 MVC if you want to stick to Java.
After you see that Server works, just write a simple app and try sending AJAX queries.

You can use Gson library to parse and create JSON objects that you can send back and forth.
Best of luck, seems like a very confusing and tough project.

Comment: A client told me he needs an app for his page to display new posts and gives push notifications of posts , this is what I need

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer, instead use comment section for clarifications.